# Create bubble chart for number of feature occurances with R

Tags: r, charts, visualization, bubble-chart

I have a table with some entries and want to visualize the number of occurances for each. I wanted to use a kind of bubble chart (for lack of better term) for this.

For example like this, just with a solid coloring and size relative to number of occurances [image]

I tried to use the ggplot2 geom_point() graph, but there I need specific x-y coordinates for each point, but I want the more or less random but not overlapping, like above.

Can I achieve this using some form of ggplot without trying to arrange the points by myself?

Does someone know of a better R package for this? I dont exactly know what to search for, for this kind of visualization, I'm not a native English speaker, so hints in that direction would also be welcome.

EDIT: the igraph package empty graph produces overlapping vertexes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the `igraph` package to make a graph with no links connecting the nodes. The default layout will keep them from bumping into each other. Since you did not provide data, I use arbitrary sizes and labels.

```
library(igraph)
g = make_empty_graph(26)

## Arbitrary Labels
V(g)$label = LETTERS

## Arbitrary sizes
V(g)$size  = sample(20:40, 26, replace=TRUE)

plot(g, vertex.color="lightgreen")
```

[image: Bubbles]

It looks like the number of occurrences you want to use for the size includes some large numbers.  You will probably need to scale them to use for the node size.

### Addition

The default layout for this graph is Fruchterman-Reingold (`layout_with_fr`),  but there are other layouts that *should* separate disconnected nodes.  Two others that worked for me are the graphopt  algorithm (`layout_with_graphopt`)and  Davidson and Harel (`layout_with_dh`)  which lays out the nodes in a rectangular array.

```
LO_GO = layout_with_go(g)
plot(g, vertex.color="lightgreen", layout = LO_GO)

LO_DH = layout_with_dh(g)
plot(g, vertex.color="lightgreen", layout = LO_DH)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats nearly what I want, but when I copied your example, I got overlapping vertexes (with your original values). See the image I edited in my post.

Comment: That is odd. I did not edit the image.  Just now,  I started a fresh R session and pasted that code into the command window and got the same picture i had before - no overlaps.